Libvirt default network is active but virt-install does not see it
When I'm trying to start a new vm on default network, I'm getting an error:
ERROR    Network not found: no network with matching name 'default'

Meanwhile, sudo virsh net-list --all states for the network 'default' state 'active'.
'ip a' yields:
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c1:fa:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


What could be the problem?
P.S.
virt-builder ubuntu-20.04 --format qcow2 --output ubuntu.qcow2 --root-password password:1111

virt-install --import --name ubuntu --cpu host --ram 4096 --disk ubuntu.qcow2 --os-variant ubuntu20.04 --network network=default

Can't even imaging what is going wrong.
